# Casting from HttpServletRequest to WebRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used:

Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 , Java 8, maven

I have this method in 1 of the class

```
private Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                   boolean includeStackTrace) {

        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request);
        return this.errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(request, includeStackTrace)

    }
```

But I don't know how to cast from `javax.servlet.http HttpServletRequest` `org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest`

```
The method getErrorAttributes(WebRequest, boolean) in the type ErrorAttributes is not applicable for the arguments (HttpServletRequest, 
     boolean)
```

Comment: If anybody is still interested in obtaining a `WebRequest` from a `HttpServletRequest` , here is how: `WebRequest webRequest = new ServletWebRequest(request);`

Comment: And how about vice versa.  HttpServletRequest  from WebRequest

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't need to cast `HttpServletRequest` to `WebRequest`. What you need is using `WebRequest` in your controller method.

```
@GetMapping("/endpoint")
public .. endpont(HttpServletRequest request, WebRequest webRequest) {
    getErrorAttributes(request, webRequest, true);
}
```

And change to your `getErrorAttributes` method

```
private Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(HttpServletRequest request, WebRequest webRequest,
                                               boolean includeStackTrace) {

    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request);
    return this.errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(webRequest, includeStackTrace)

}
```

Comment: You can remove 
RequestAttributes requestAttributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request);

and the HttpServletRequest from getErrorAtributes aswell